# How do I get MVC installed into Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Does anyone have any basic instructions for setting up a first MVC project in Visual Studio 2008? I just installed Visual Studio 2008 and I am finding various instructions on how to set up the programming environment, but it's very complicated and there is no way to tell if the route I am taking is the best one.

If I want to start developing a MVC project, what do I need to do in order to get it going?

I am very confused by the "Web Client Guidance" instructions.  For example, they don't say where to put the Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll file.

Comment: This is a question about developing for MVC. It definitely belongs here.

Comment: I wonder if things have changed since I first asked this question long ago in 2009?  I am now a Java developer and so I don't know what is happening in C#-land.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Visual studio 2008 sp1 to get mvc installed...

Here is the download [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/)

To get started [With MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

**System Requirements**
**Supported Operating Systems**: Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP
.NET 3.5 SP1. Visual Studio 2008, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 or Visual Web Developer 2008 SP1 are required to use certain parts of this feature.

Comment: I knew it would turn out to be easy.  Thanks very much for the link... I needed that!  :-)

Comment: the problem was that a Google search started me out on the wrong site and I got detoured and confused.  here is the site i was at:  http://www.codeplex.com/webclientguidance

Answer (score 3):

The official Microsoft MVC links for Visual Studio 2008 now seem to be dead.

To get this working on my old Vista laptop (with Visual Studio 2008) in 2013, I did this:
- Upgraded to Visual Studio SP1
- Followed this link to download and install "AspNetMVCRC-setup.msi" (1.74 MB):
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141184&clcid=0x409

Once that was in place, my old Visual Studio let me create "Web | ASP.NET MVC Web Application" projects.   Took about an hour and a half from end-to-end.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to download MVC from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/).

After that, proceed with the installation.

You might want to refer to the [tutorial for starters](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

All I did was install the MVC installer and I opened their example app and it worked.\

[MVC Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en)